# Boolean, True & True & True coming in as False?

Tags: excel, vba, boolean

Is there a reason this is coming in as false?  Below is the VBA output when debugging:

```
?A + B > X & A + B <= Y & C = 0
False

?A + B > X & A + B <= Y
True
?C=0
True

?A + B > X
True
?A + B <= Y
True
```

Comment: You know that the ampersand (&) is the string concatenation operator, right?

Comment: so to say "true and true and true" you don't write it as "true & true & true"?

Comment: Correct. It is:  `True And True And True`

Comment: thanks got it, newb to programming so much appreciated

Comment: Shall I make a short answer out of this for you to accept?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into here is that the ampersand `&` is the string concatenation operator in VBA.

To evaluate logical logical conditions you must use the `And` operator, like so:

```
?True And True
```

Comment: The "fun" part is that `And` is a *logical* or *bit-wise* operator *depending on context*.. gotta love VBA :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278455.aspx), Arithmetic (and &) are evaluated before Comparison and Logical operators.

So `A + B > X & A + B <= Y & C = 0` evaluate as `(A + B) > (X & A + B) <= (Y & C) = 0` which is probably not what you expected.